# own personal like button

Tags: php

I have created a like button on my own site (not Facebook like button). when a user clicks the like button the count increases by 1 and link becomes inactive.
But the problem is if I refresh the page the count increases automatically.
need help its in php.
Code is

```php
if(@$_GET['click']=="like")
{
    $_SESSION['like']=1;
    $lk=$row['likes']+1;
    $iid=$row['id'];
    mysql_query("UPDATE `blog` SET `likes`=$lk WHERE id=$iid ");
    $row['likes']++;
    $lmsg="<img title='Already Liked' src='a_data/upg.png'>";
}
else
{
    $lmsg="<a href='viewblog.php?id=".$gid."&click=like'> <img title='Like It' src='a_data/up.png'></a>";
}

echo "<div id='like'>".$row['likes']."</div> ".$lmsg;
```

Comment: @Steve There is no need for all those `language: lang-` edits. If the appropriate tag is there, highlighting is automatic.

Comment: Are you also using JavaScript for this process? Can we see that too?

Comment: can i know beeter way to do it.?

Comment: Justin @ no javascript only pure php..

Comment: @Bart Sometimes I add the highlighting tag because I can't tell if the highlighting is working. The black and rust colors used in the PHP highlighting are really hard for me to tell apart without zooming in.

Comment: So just have a check if the tag is there next time @Steve. Or if it isn't there and should be, add it. You should rarely need the special formatting.

Comment: Sorry, I think there's some confusion on my end. Was there already a <!-- language tag and I added another one?

Comment: No, and you don't need one @Steve. If there is an appropriate tag below a question, highlighting is automatic. See the [php] tag that's below this one which was added by a user in the 2nd revision.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that question tags did that. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use, javascript cookie and php sessions to prevent refresh and repeated clicks.
And if you're looking for a permanent solution for preventing never like again you need to add user ip to a mysql table with the liked entry id.

But this way, you will have only one like from every ip. (Think a company with 100 people working. Only one of them can like your entry.)

Exact and proper solution is a membership. Where every user is identified with a unique id.

Also just to reply your refresh question, you can edit your code like this:

```
if(@$_GET['click']=="like" && !isset($_SESSION['like']))
{
$_SESSION['like']=1;
$lk=$row['likes']+1;
$iid=$row['id'];
mysql_query("UPDATE `blog` SET `likes`=$lk WHERE id=$iid ");
$row['likes']++;
$lmsg="<img title='Already Liked' src='a_data/upg.png'>";
}
else
{
 $lmsg="<a href='viewblog.php?id=".$gid."&click=like'> <img title='Like It' src='a_data/up.png'>   </a>";
}
```

Comment: i tried still happens the same..
it gets increment evrytime i refresh.

Comment: Did you add `session_start()` at the begining of the file?

Comment: but now new problm came forward that.. the page relods evrytime i click the like button and it the count doesnt increment on othr pages eithr..

Comment: Because you're using the same session key for others also. So if you add a unique key for the sesion key or if you change the session values to array with the liked entry id's it will be ok i suppose.